# How can I get different pictures being shown depending on the different options being selected in a select box?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm having a select box with multiple options and I'm trying to figure out a way to make a picture appear for each of the options, depending on the one that is being selected. I'm in great need of help here as I need to make this work as soon as possible. I'm trying to make it happen automatically (when the option is selected) or with a button (depending on the option that is selected) but so far I couldn't come up with anything that would work. Any help is seriously appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what have you done so far? show your work

Comment: Look at this example: http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#custom-data

Answer (score 0):

You should check the value of the selected `<option>` and change the `<img>` src to the path of the image you want. To do that, you need to call a function when the user change the `<select>`'s `<option>`.

Here is a sample:

#### HTML

The `onchage="changeImage();` makes `<select>` call the function `changeImage()` every time a new `<option>` is selected.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <select id="selectbox" onchange="changeImage();">
        <option value="html">HTML</option>
        <option value="css">CSS</option>
        <option value="javascript">JavaScript</option>
    </select>
    <img id="img" src="" />
</body>
</html>
```

#### JavaScript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function changeImage(){
        var selectBox = document.getElementById("selectbox");
        var selectedValue = selectBox.options[selectBox.selectedIndex].value;
        document.getElementById("img").src = selectedValue + ".png";
    }
</script>
```

You can check the value of the selected `<option>` with `selectBox.options[selectBox.selectedIndex].innerHTML` too. That will make it easier if you have a lot of options and do not want to set the `value` of everything.

If the images on your server have the same names as the value of each option, you don't even need to use a if statement. However, if the images are in different places or have different names/extensions, you can set the code like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function changeImage(){     
        var selectBox = document.getElementById("selectbox");
        var selectedValue = selectBox.options[selectBox.selectedIndex].value;
        var img = document.getElementById("img");
        if (selectedValue == "html"){
            img.src = "images/html.png";
        } else if (selectedValue == "css"){
            img.src = "images/css.jpeg";
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you a lot! Your response works wonders! I greatly appreciate your help!

Comment: @user2220872 maybe a bit late, but can you mark it as the correct answer?